# Convergence of $ a_n = \frac{(2n+3)!}{(n+1)!} $

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

Take the sequence:

$$ a_n = \frac{(2n+3)!}{(n+1)!} $$

At first I just took out the factorals but then when I evaluated it was wrong. I researched a little and found Stirling's formula but I don't really get it. By just evaluating at $n, n-1, n-2$ we can see that the numerator survives so ht limit is infinity but it's just a supposition. Thanks.

Comment: Notice that $2n+3>n+1$, and consequently implies $(2n+3)!>(n+1)!$. Hence the limit diverges and so does the sequence

Answer (score 4):

$(2n+3)!\ge (n+2)!=(n+1)!(n+2)$.

Answer (score 2):

$$Hint:$$ The number $a_n$ is the product of $n+2$ numbers, each of which is greater than or equal to $2$.

Answer (score 2):

$$a_n = \frac{(2n+3)!}{(n+1)!} = \frac{(2n+3)(2n+2)\cdots(n+2)(n+1)!}{(n+1)!} = (2n+3)(2n+2)\cdots(n+2) > n+2$$ for all $n \ge 1$.

Answer (score 2):

> *I researched a little and found Stirling's formula but I don't really get it*

Even if you do not need it (as shown in answers and commants)
$$a_n = \frac{(2n+3)!}{(n+1)!}\implies \log(a_n)=\log((2n+3)!)-\log(n+1)!$$
Now using Stirling
$$\log(p!)=p (\log (p)-1)+\frac{1}{2} \log (2 \pi  p)+O\left(\frac{1}{p}\right)$$ apply it twice and continue with Taylor series to get
$$\log(a_n)=n (\log (n)-1+2 \log (2))+\left(\log \left(8 \sqrt{2}\right)+2 \log
   \left({n}\right)\right)++O\left(\frac{1}{p}\right)$$ making $a_n \sim n^n$.